# Do I need a work visa to attend a conference?

Tags: uk-citizens, netherlands, working-visas, brexit, conferences

I'm a British citizen and my company is sending me to a conference in the EU (the Netherlands) later this month.

Do I need to apply for a work visa while I am attending the conference?

This is my first time travelling to Europe since Brexit, and I am a little unsure of the rules. The Foreign Office website was quite vague on if it is necessary or not. No-one at the company seems to know either.

Does anyone have any advice on this?

Comment: The UK gov travel advice site for the Netherlands says *You can travel to countries in the Schengen area for up to 90 days in any 180-day period without a visa. This applies if you travel as a tourist, to visit family or friends, to attend business meetings, cultural or sports events, or for short-term studies or training.* Which covers your conference https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/netherlands/entry-requirements

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You do not need a visa or work authorisation to travel to the EU / Schengen area to attend conferences or trainings. This is fully within the scope of “business travel” covered by short-stay Schengen visas (for people who require one) or visa-free travel (for people who do not, including British citizens). Even company-internal trainings would be allowed.

Comment: Including a source for this (perhaps just cribbing it from the one quoted in a [comment on the question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/176169/do-i-need-a-work-visa-to-attend-a-conference#comment442130_176169)) would be helpful. Otherwise, it's just "some guy (with a lot of rep at [travel.se], to be fair) on the internet says".